# whitespaces when adding partial template using EJS

Tags: node.js, dom, express, sails.js, ejs

I am using SailsJS with EJS engine.

When I add partials using **<% include partials/template.ejs %>** or **<% partial('partials/template.ejs')** in the layout file, I get whitespaces before the compiled HTML code (template.ejs).

Note that when I copy paste the template.ejs content in the layout (not using include/partials) the whitespaces are gone.

See images below:

**1st part:** code.

**2nd part:** chrome DOM.

**3rd part:** whitespace element inspection (DOM properties)

[image: 1st part: code. 2nd part: chrome DOM. 3rd part: whitespace element inspection (DOM properties)]

Comment: I also discovered this, this is because of the parser (with regular expressions) used in the template engine, so you can't fix this, I made my own ejs template engine simpleT (https://github.com/micnic/simpleT/) with a bit more complex parser, it is still very raw and can have some bugs, if you want to use it and find some difficulties just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. 
What I did was very simple.

Go to ejs module index.js file.
Find partial function.
Find this part of code:

```
var source = options.cache
? cache[key] || (cache[key] = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'))
: fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
```

and replace it with

```
var source = options.cache
? cache[key] || (cache[key] = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8').trim())
: fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8').trim();
```

So, what I did is just used trim() java script function.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: i tried this, it doesn't work, i am not even sure how sails renders the partials, which library it calls. maybe it calls local-ejs ? i tried to modify this code there, but still, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when using ejs render. Some white space was included in my code, causing positionnement problems.

I looked everwhere on the internet, and finally build my own solution :

```
    var clean= function(selecteur) {
        var save=new Array();
        selecteur.children().each(function() {
            save.push(this);
        });
        selecteur.empty();
        for(i in save) {
            selecteur.append(save[i]);
        }
    };
```

This function can be called on any jquery selector container that need to be cleaned from any whitespace. It works basically by saving all your contents in a local variable, emptying your container, then, adding your saved contents.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing and at least in my case this was due to the EJS partial function using

```
fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
```

which according to

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1918

does not remove the UTF-8 BOM.  While it would be nice if the EJS engine stripped away the BOM for us, saving the partial files in UTF-8 without the BOM solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%_` tag instead of `<%` tag.

Read more about it [here](https://github.com/mde/ejs#tags)

> The <%_ would strip off any trailing whitespaces that <% leaves upon rendering