# Whitespaces bug in Sails JS + How does Sails JS render an EJS template?

Tags: sails.js

Simple code like the following renders several white spaces before the rendered template.

```
<%= include partials/editableMenuRow.ejs %>
```

I add trim() to the file reader in ejs-locals\index.js:

```
var source = options.cache
? cache[key] || (cache[key] = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')**.trim()**)
: fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')**.trim()**;
```

However, I am not even sure sails calls this code, I added dummy console.log but I get nothing!

**Which functions/libs sails call in order to render a partial?**

I am trying to fix the bug, my client side code is getting huge and this is so PAINFUL! :)

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior at all.  Can you post the code for your partial?

Comment: A few partials reproduce this error, some don't, sometimes it is exactly the same partial. I really cannot tell when it happens, but I saw a few posts from others that it happened to them. This is one of my partials:

<div class="form-group">
  <label class='col-md-3 control-label' for='birthday'>Birthday</label>
  <div class='col-md-7 controls'>
    <input name="birthday" class="form-control date" data-rule-required='true' placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text"></input>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: see this post, someone suggested solution but it doesn't work as I am not sure how sails renders the EJS and which library it uses:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620128/whitespaces-when-adding-partial-template-using-ejs